# Matplotlib Xticks Confusion

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a bar chart using matplotlib for two target groups: Sale '1' and not Sale '0'. My data:

```
Sale     item                 Count
0        1.0                   3520
         2.0                      9
         3.0                   2095
         4.0                    586
         5.0                    609
         6.0                    427
         7.0                    101
         8.0                    111
1        1.0                     88
         3.0                     43
         4.0                     28
         5.0                     36
         6.0                     16
         7.0                      3
         8.0                      4
```

The current code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
labels=['1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0', '5.0', '6.0', '7.0', '8.0']
itemSale0 = X_train[X_train.hasSale==0]
itemSale0=itemSale0.groupby('item').size().values
x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars
rects1=ax.bar(x - width/2, itemSale0, width, label='Not Sale')

labels=['1.0','3.0','4.0', '5.0', '6.0', '7.0', '8.0']
itemSale1 = X_train[X_train.hasSale==1]
itemSale1 = itemSale1.groupby('item').size().values    
x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars
rects2=ax.bar(x + width/2, itemSale1, width, label='Sale')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title('Sale by Traffice Source')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
```

Problem : items where sale is '0' are 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0 does not match to the item numbers where sale exist '1' are 1.0,3.0,4.0, 5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0 in graph xticks.

```
items where sale is not are 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0 
items where sale are        1.0,   ,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0
```

Both are overlapping please see attached screen,it cannot distinguish at item 2.0 where 9 items are not sold and its bar has merged to xticks item 3 where 43 items sold, how can I show xticks which can separate both items 2.0 for not sale 9 and 3.0 for sale 43 items

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of bar plots is quite easy to draw with Seaborn. The `hue` keyword assigns a color depending on the given column and creates "dodged" bars.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate(f'{height:.0f}',
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sale': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'item': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   'Count': [3520, 9, 2095, 586, 609, 427, 101, 111, 88, 43, 28, 36, 16, 3, 4]})

ax = sns.barplot(x='item', y='Count', hue='Sale', data=df)
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_title('Sale by Traffice Source')
autolabel(ax.containers[0])
autolabel(ax.containers[1])
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, ['No sale', 'Sale'])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: The default legend puts the values of the 'Sale' (`hue='Sale'`) column into the legend. These currently are 0 and 1. To automatically have the desired strings in the legend, one could rename the column values: `df['Sale'] = np.where(df['Sale'] == 0, 'No sale', 'Sale')`.

Comment: i am very naive in matplotlib and seaborn, so it means seaborn is more flexible than using matplotlib right?

Comment: Seaborn does a lot of things more automatically than pure matplotlib. If you need something special (e.g. the autolabeling) you can adapt the plot via matplotlib. See Seaborn's [example gallery](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html) to get an idea of what's possible with little code. The same can be accomplished by matplotlib, but would need much more programming.